# AndEngine threading model: how to wait until animation stop?

Tags: android, multithreading, andengine

sorry if this question exists somewhere

I am developing a very like memory matrix game, my first game using AndEngine. In my game, at the loading matrix stage, i have to ensure that only after the matrix has been loaded, the game enter playing state (only then, user's actions will be processed). So, in the procedure below to embed Modifier to tiles, i used `CountDownLatch`:

```
public static void loadingBoardAnimation(Sprite board,
        List<AnimatedSprite> tiles, final Set<Integer> keys,
        Runnable playing) {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(keys.size());

    for (final AnimatedSprite tile : tiles) {
        /* Appear */
        MoveModifier initialMove = new MoveModifier(1, board.getX(),
                board.getY(), tile.getX(), tile.getY());

        /* Delay 1 second */
        DelayModifier delay = new DelayModifier(1);

        SequenceEntityModifier animation = new SequenceEntityModifier(
                new IEntityModifierListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onModifierStarted(
                            IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onModifierFinished(
                            IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                        if (keys.contains(tile.getTag())) {
                            tile.animate(50, false);
                        }
                        latch.countDown();
                    }

                }, initialMove, delay);
        tile.registerEntityModifier(animation);
    }

    /* Wait until animation finishes */
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it seem when this procedure is executed, it block entire game. I placed break point in `latch.countDown()` and see that the debugger never get there. So, i guess the AndEngine model uses event-driven architecture in only one thread (new arrived animation can not be dispatched), is that right? And in this case, anybody can suggest me a solution :-).... Thanks in advance